# Differences Between Hooking a Function onto Prototype or Not

Tags: javascript, prototype

What is the differences between:

```
function Gandalf() {
    this.color = 'grey';
}

Gandalf.prototype.comeBack = function() {
    this.color = 'white';
}
```

And:

```
function Gandalf() {
    this.color = 'grey';

    this.comeBack = function() {
        this.color = 'white';
        return this;
    };
}
```

And under which circumstances should I hook the method onto the prototype, or not?

Comment: depends on how many Galdalfs you've got.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

Comment: @thg435 Depends on how many __Galdalfs__ you've got? You just ruined a great comment because of a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright Agent Kay, I'll approach this question in a different way than Esailija did. Let's begin with simple objects. For example say you already have an object called `gandalf`:

```
var gandalf = {
    color: "grey",
    comeBack: function () {
        this.color = "white";
        return this;
    }
};
```

There are no constructors in this code. Hence this code is easy to understand. Am I right or am I right?

---

Alright, now I'm going to do something awesome. I'll create `radagast` from `gandalf`:

```
var radagast = Object.create(gandalf);

radagast.color = "brown";
```

What's happening here? Let's break it up:

1. We create a new object called `radagast` from `gandalf` using [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). Hence `radagast` inherits from `gandalf`.
2. We set the `color` of `radagast` to brown instead of grey.

To make it even more simple imagine you and I had the following conversation:

`I: Hey Agent Kay, I met Radagast yesterday.`

`U: Who's Radagast?`

`I: Hmm... do you know who's Gandalf?`

`U: Yes, I do.`

`I: Well Radagast is just like Gandalf except that he's brown instead of white.`

This is exactly how inheritance works in JavaScript. You see JavaScript has prototypal inheritance. In prototypal inheritance objects inherits from other objects. In this case `radagast` inherited from `gandalf`.

---

Now they way prototypal inheritance is usually implemented in JavaScript is weird. I call it the [constructor pattern of prototypal inheritance](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#constructors_vs_prototypes). For example, take your code:

```
function Gandalf() {
    this.color = "grey";
}

Gandalf.prototype.comeBack = function() {
    this.color = "white";
    return this;
};
```

Now when you create an instance of `Gandalf` what object does the instance inherit from? It inherits from `Gandalf.prototype`:

```
var gandalf = new Gandalf;
alert(Object.getPrototypeOf(gandalf) === Gandalf.prototype); // true
```

What's happening when you say `new Gandalf` is:

```
var gandalf = Object.create(Gandalf.prototype);
Gandalf.call(gandalf);
```

If you expand `Gandalf.call(gandalf)` the you get:

```
var gandalf = Object.create(Gandalf.prototype);
gandalf.color = "grey";
```

---

Now take your second example:

```
function Gandalf() {
    this.color = "grey";

    this.comeBack = function() {
        this.color = "white";
        return this;
    };
}
```

In this case when you create an instance of `Gandalf` you're essentially doing this:

```
var gandalf = Object.create(Gandalf.prototype);

gandalf.color = "grey";

gandalf.comeBack = function () {
    this.color = "white";
    return this;
};
```

Hence every time you create a new `Gandalf` you create a new function `comeBack`. Thus if you call `new Gandalf` 10 times you'll have 10 different `comeBack` functions as well.

Compared to this in the first example since `comeBack` is defined on `Gandalf.prototype`, every time we call `new Gandalf` we get a new object which inherits from `Gandalf.prototype`. Hence there's only one `comeBack` function which is shared amongst all instances of `Gandalf`. Isn't that better?

---

Essentially think of your first example like this:

```
var gandalfPrototype = {
    create: function () {
        var gandalf = Object.create(this);
        gandalf.color = "grey";
        return gandalf;
    },
    comeBack: function () {
        this.color = "white";
        return this;
    }
};

var gandalf = gandalfPrototype.create(); // there's only one comeBack function
```

Similarly your second example is equivalent to this:

```
var gandalfPrototype = {
    create: function () {
        var gandalf = Object.create(this);

        gandalf.color = "grey";

        gandalf.comeBack = function () {
            this.color = "white";
            return this;
        };

        return gandalf;
    }
};

var gandalf = gandalfPrototype.create(); // there's 1 comeBack for each instance
```

Remember that when you use `new` before a function call you're actually inheriting from the `prototype` of the function. Not the function itself.

---

Finally I would like to say (because I'm a big fan of J.R.R. Tolkien) that this is the way I would write your code:

```
var wizard = {
    create: function (color) {
        var wizard = Object.create(this);
        wizard.color = color;
        return wizard;
    }
};

var gandalf = wizard.create("grey");

gandalf.comeBack = function () {
    this.color = "white";
    return this;
};

var saruman = wizard.create("white");
var radagast = wizard.create("brown");
```

Thank you for reading my answer.

Comment: saras!!!Su answer dedo che aadit bhai...I remember you answered my question also in a very simplistic way!!!seems proto is your forte..keep it up Chokraa!!!

Comment: Very clever and concise answer, much kudos to you sir!

Comment: `Hence every time you create a new Gandalf you create a new function comeBack. Thus if you call new Gandalf 10 times you'll have 10 different comeBack functions as well.

Compared to this in the first example since comeBack is defined on Gandalf.prototype, every time we call new Gandalf we get a new object which inherits from Gandalf.prototype. Hence there's only one comeBack function which is shared amongst all instances of Gandalf. Isn't that better?` little difficult to understand...can i aheva short exlanation to it...a comment will do

Answer (score 3):

The reason to put it on prototype is because every object created can use the same function object (functions are merely callable objects), they only need different identity and data. But in the second case you are creating unique function objects for each object even though they can use the same function object.

Since you seem to know PHP, the difference would be similar in PHP:

```
class Gandalf {
    public $color = "grey";

    public function comeBack() {
        $this->color = "white";
    }
}


class Gandalf {
    public $color = "grey";

    //Create the method inside constructor everytime
    public function __construct() {
        $this->comeBack = function() {
            $this->color = "white";
            return $this;
        }->bindTo($this, $this);
    }
}
```

It is hard to say when to use the other when performance is not a concern. Personally the 
obfuscation of the constructor function and the [additional indentation level](http://jsfiddle.net/WDAN7/) are enough for me to prefer the prototype.

Comment: Note that even though the function objects themselves are duplicated, they can share their code (but not the scope chain)

Comment: @JanDvorak I didn't mean code is duplicated, that would be insane. Let me clarify.

Answer (score 0):

To answer:

> under which circumstances should I hook the method onto the prototype, or not?

If you have a function that need to access private `vars` of an object created with a constructor function, it needs to be inside constructor function.

```
function Gandalf() {
    var age = '30000'; //approximate

    this.alertAge1 = function() {
        alert( age );
    };
}

Gandalf.prototype.alertAge2 = function() {
    // age not visible from here
};
```